# Código JS deja de funcionar

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

estoy trabajando con unos filtros de tablas en Bootstrap, tengo un botón que carga las tablas y otro que es para ocultarlas y un select para el filtro de las tablas, el problema viene porque en un inicio todo carga bien y funciona a la perfección pero llega un momento en el que ya no me hace los filtros ni me ocultan las tablas.

Les comparto lo que tengo

```html
   <a class="btn" id="entregadosim">Pedidos Entregados</a>
<div id="con4"></div>
<button class="btn" style="border-color: #000; " onclick="ocultar();">Ocultar</button>
```

En este div cargo la tabla con Ajax

```js
$('#entregadosim').click(function(){
  var Fechain=document.getElementById('f1').value;
  var Fechafin=document.getElementById('f2').value;

  var ruta="Fein="+Fechain+"&Fefin="+Fechafin;

  $.ajax({
    url: 'pag/entregados.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: ruta,
  })

  .done(function(res){
    $('#con4').html(res)
    //$('#f1').val('');
    //$('#f2').val('');
  })

  .fail(function(){
    console.log("error");
  })
  .always(function(){
    console.log("complete");
  })
});
```

El id de mi contenedor es "tablas"

Y aquí están los scripts de los filtros y el de ocultar tabla

```js
<script>
  document.getElementById('selectCategory').reset();
</script>
```

Y este es el script de los filtros

```js
<script>
  $("#opciones").change(function () {
    if(this.value != "Todos")
      {
    
    var data = this.value.split(" ");
    
    var jo = $("#tabla").find("tr");
    if (this.value == "") {
        jo.show();
        return;
    }
 
    jo.hide();
    
    jo.filter(function (i, v) {
        var $t = $(this);
        for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
            if ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    })
    
    .show();
      }
    }).focus(function () {
    this.value = "";
    $(this).css({
        "color": "black"
    });
    $(this).unbind('focus');
    }).css({
    "color": "#C0C0C0"
    });
</script>
```

Son dos tablas las que estoy utilizando, al hacerlo por primera vez si quiero consultar los filtros de la segunda tabla y ocultarlo lo hace bien, pero si lo hago con la primera y luego lo quiero consultar con la segunda tabla, en la segunda ya no lo hace pero en la primera sí, no sé si me podrían ayudar, muchas gracias